# Replace View with another View

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

I got a XIB-File with a View. Between the TabBar and the TopBar I have placed another View.
Now I want to replace the second View with other Views. Is this possible? And if it is, how can I do this? Code like "addSubview" oder "pushViewController" doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

`addSubview` would be used say if you programmatically created a UIButton and wanted to add it to the view.

`pushViewController` requires you to have a [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Your question doesnt clearly explain what you want to do.

Do you want to switch a view with another view, like an image rollover in HTML?

Or do you want to go to another view controller that has other objects on it?

Comment: I want to go to another ViewController that has other objects on it.

Comment: Ok, but then I have to use a NvigationController. The question that I have now is, how can I add a NavigationController to a UIView. It is so confusing.